# pulling out sub-columns in a data frame to the same "level" as the others

Tags: r, subdirectory, sublist

Apologies if this has already been answered somewhere else.
So I have a dataset in R that contains a certain amount of variables. When I preview it some of the variables I need for my analysis are there but outside the count of the variables as if they were in subsections of the dataframe itself.

Now I managed to access some of it using sapply (these were sublists in the dataframe) but there are several others I cannot.
I am still unable to access a column that is containing the country information for my data set.
It looks as if it is contained in another variable.
Any suggestions how to bring this variable on the same plane as the others in the data set and eliminate subfolders?

Comment: It sounds like with a sample of your data this would be very straightforward to answer. Without it, and only a vague _description_ of your data it is almost impossible.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: thank you, I managed to solve by referring to the objects in this format '(foldername).(subfolder).....not sure is the most scalable way of operating but it works...